# SQL: How do I get the last updated row to use in a trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-update, getlatest

So I got this trigger that looks like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trLoadingOvertime
ON trailerScheme
FOR UPDATE AS
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trailerScheme 
WHERE DATEDIFF(mi, trailerScheme.expectedFinishTime, trailerScheme.finishTime) > 15) > 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO errorTable2
SELECT trailerSchemeID FROM inserted

END
```

and between BEGIN and END I need to insert values into errorTable2 from the trailerScheme that was just updated.

I hope someone can help me

Update:
When I use this code it just give me NULL

```
DECLARE @id INT
SELECT
@id = deleted.trailerSchemeID
FROM
inserted
INNER JOIN
deleted
ON inserted.trailerSchemeID = deleted.trailerSchemeID

INSERT INTO errorTable2 VALUES(@id)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to insert a new row into errorTable2, with values from the trailerScheme that was just updated

Comment: And what happens with your `INSERT`? Does it give you an error, it doesn't insert? BTW you don't need `BEGIN ... END` since `INSERT` is the only statement.

Comment: well I tried allot of different things and some times it just doesn't do anything, sometimes it inserts NULL and sometimes it don't work... I've tried with inserted and deleted, but is there some way to get the latest row that was updated or the row that just triggered the trigger?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like **triggers** are **highly** vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trLoadingOvertime
ON trailerScheme
FOR UPDATE AS
  INSERT INTO errorTable2
  SELECT trailerSchemeID 
    FROM inserted
   WHERE DATEDIFF(mi, expectedFinishTime, finishTime) > 15
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45828/1)** demo.

Comment: No that doesn't work. Isn't there just a simple way to get the last updated row or the row that triggered the trigger?

Comment: **First of all** how exactly it doesn't work? To clarify things, post some sample data (a few rows) and desired result in both tables and an update statement in your question. **Secondly** in SQL Server there's no such thing as last updated row. Trigger is invoked on a per statement (not per row) basis. That's way you have inserted and deleted virtual tables, which contain ALL affected rows.

Comment: @NiklasJensen Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: I figured it out my self. But thanks for your time and effort :)

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out my self. Here is the correct code:

```
DROP TRIGGER trLoadingOvertime
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trLoadingOvertime
ON trailerScheme
FOR INSERT AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT expectedFinishTime, finishTime
FROM inserted
WHERE DATEDIFF(mi, expectedFinishTime, finishTime) > 15)
BEGIN
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @exFTime DATETIME
DECLARE @fTime DATETIME
DECLARE @delay INT

SET @id = (SELECT trailerSchemeID FROM inserted)
SET @exFTime = (SELECT expectedFinishTime FROM inserted)
SET @fTime = (SELECT finishTime FROM inserted)
SET @delay = (SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, @exFTime, @fTime))

INSERT INTO errorTable VALUES(@id, @delay)

END
```

I was trying to get inserted, but the problem was that this trigger was called by an update and therefore the inserted was empty.